# Place Text Adjacent to Logo

Tags: html, css

i am new to HTML 5 , but i want to place a text next to the logo image. I have tried the following code but does not work

```
  <header> 
    <a href="/" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
      <img src="/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" 
      style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
   </a>
   <h1>CAGD Data Centre Access Form</h1>
</header>
```

the text is wrapped with the h1 element.

the css codes for the header

```
  header {
    background-color:ash;
    text-align:left;
    height:35px;
    padding:12px; 
      }
```

any help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h1` elements by default display as **blocks**. Use `span`

```css
header {
  background-color: ash;
  text-align: left;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
    <img src="/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" style="width:30px;height:30px;" />
  </a>
  <span>CAGD Data Centre Access Form</span>
</header>
```

If you have no options to change the element type to `span`, then use `display:inline;`

```css
header {

    background-color: ash;

    text-align: left;

    height: 35px;

    padding: 12px;

  }

  h1 {

    display: inline;

  }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
    <img src="/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" style="width:30px;height:30px;" />
  </a>
  <h1>CAGD Data Centre Access Form</h1>
</header>
```

**Or**, use the `:after` pseudo selector

```css
header {
  background-color: ash;
  text-align: left;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 12px;
}
#logo:after {
  content: 'CAGD Data Centre Access Form';
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
    <img src="/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" style="width:30px;height:30px;" />
  </a>
</header>
```